# Conditional Formatting one column of date/time data compared to another colum date/time data 4 hour breach and 1 hour breach

Tags: conditional-formatting

I'd like to conditionally format one column's date/time cell data if the time is over one hour after the date/time cell data on the same row in the previous column by making it red and bold.  I've tried to look at similar questions on here but can't seem to make it work.

eg.

If A2 has 21/01/2021 8:00
and B2 has 21/01/2021 9:05
and C2 has 21/01/2021 8:37

then B2 data will be formatted red and bold because the hour has been breached, whereas C2 data will remain non-bold and black.

I also need a similar formula for a 4 hour breach.

Comment: Welcome to [su]. What app are you using ( Excel, Sheets, Numbers, Calc, ...)? Also please show what you tried and add a link or two to some of the questions that you already read (better if they are close to what you are looking).

Comment: In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text - [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

**To test, with your data (A2, B2, C2):**
Enter `=ABS(OFFSET(B2,0,-1)-B2)>(1/24)` in B3, copy to C3.
For an allowed DIFFERENCE of one hour (1/24) either before OR after.
`=(OFFSET(B2,0,-1)-B2)>(1/24)` or `=(B2-OFFSET(B2,0,-1))>(1/24)` for just before or after - try it, to find out which you want.

Note 1:
`(OFFSET(B2,0,-1)` = "the value in the cell one column left of B2"
Note 2:
Time and date is stored as "1.0" per one day, with the integer part telling how far it is from 1970-01-01, and by that a fraction of 1/24 is one hour.

---

**To use:**

- Select B2,
- enter Conditional formatting and
- set a formula;
- enter `ABS(OFFSET(B2,0,-1)-B2)>(1/24)`

Also set the formatting to use if TRUE to whatever you like; i.e red and bold.

---

Change 1/24 to 4/24 for a four hour difference limit.

---